# Probability that n parts form a closed polygon

Tags: probability

A 1 m long stick is broken into n different sticks uniformly at random. What is the Probability that the sticks form a closed polygon?

If any of the sides have length >= 1/2, we cannot form the polygon

I read the linked answer here - [the probability of those n broken parts of sticks to form a closed polygon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848881/the-probability-of-those-n-broken-parts-of-sticks-to-form-a-closed-polygon) - However, I feel that the (n-1) sided simplex explanation provided here is not very intuitive at least for me.

I understand the Triangle question where we form the Inequalities and plot it to find the area of the shaded region.

However, I am unable to do this for a general n sided polygon

Comment: maybe related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162560/distribution-of-the-largest-fragment-of-a-broken-stick-spacings